# In KOTOR and other d20-based games, how does the damage roll work?

Tags: star-wars-kotor

I've been investigating a few combat systems as of late to figure out how to develop my own for a personal project.

One of the combat systems I've been focussing on has been the one in the KOTOR games. To my understanding behind the scenes it uses what is essentially the d20 system - which I have yet to really learn, mind you. So far I've made sense of attack rolls and saving throws but the damage roll is something I'm still not sure about. I spent some time looking around on the internet and got a lot of information about what the damage roll *is* but not how damage is actually *calculated*, which is what I care about.

How exactly does rolling for damage work in KOTOR? More specifically, if a weapon has a damage of "5-12", how is that damage applied during combat?

Comment: Isn't this a question for the physical [role playing games](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/) site. This site's for computer games.

Comment: The OP may also be interested in the [game development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) SE site if they're looking to develop their own combat system. I do agree that the RPG site may be best, seeing as KOTOR was based on D&D's Third Edition ruleset. Not *entirely* sure whether KOTOR II used Third Edition or 3.5 though.

Comment: @ChrisF: Ah, didn't realise there was a site for that. Wouldn't have been certain about where to post anyway as I am directly referencing the mechanics of a specific computer game. I think I know which Stack Exchange site I'm signing up for next though :)

Comment: @FAE, I thought KotOR was built on 4e dnd not 3.5

Comment: It uses neither, it uses a different system built on the same D20 SRD as third edition. It's definitively not related to 4E in any way, however.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For more general information with respect to the D20 system as a whole, you'll want to look at the [D20 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/), and if you have any further questions about it *as a system*, [RPG.Se](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) is the place to go for all your tabletop RPG Q&A needs.

That said, with respect to the specific implementation of the D20 system seen in the KOTOR games, what happens with damage rolls is that the game is abstracting the 'dice' away from the information displayed to you. A weapon with a displayed damage range of 5-12, is probably rolling 1D8+4. During combat, a hit with that weapon will deal 5-12 damage, before any other combat modifiers, whether from the characters stats, buffs, skills, or other equipment are factored in.

Comment: you might also look at Neverwinter Nights. They both use very similar systems and if i recall NWN shows more of the "behind the scenes" information (such as the die used for weapons etc)